# Add alert to TinyMCE textbox

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to add alert box to my textbox area so I can not add any alert box that will appear on the page's content.

How will I only add it?

I have tried to do this:

```
importcss_groups: [
    { text: 'Succes (Green)', value: 'alert alert-success' },
    { text: 'Info (Blue)', value: 'alert alert-info' }
]
```

i have try to make its [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/importcss/#importcss_groups):

It must be such that it makes them bootstrap alert.

My TinyMCE code:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',
theme: 'modern',
height: 350,
plugins: [
    'advlist autolink image link lists charmap anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
    'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor bbcode'
],
content_css: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
],
importcss_groups: [
    { text: 'Succes (Green)', value: 'alert alert-success' },
    { text: 'Info (Blue)', value: 'alert alert-info' }
]

});
```

I have complete its now:
i have add

```
style_formats: [{
    title: 'Succes (Grøn)',
    block: 'div',
    classes: 'alert alert-success'
}, {
    title: 'Info (Blå)',
    block: 'div',
    classes: 'alert alert-info'
}, {
    title: 'Warning (Gul)',
    block: 'div',
    classes: 'alert alert-warning'
}, {
    title: 'Danger (Rød)',
    block: 'div',
    classes: 'alert alert-danger'
}]
```

Comment: You don't even follow the example. It needs to be `importcss_groups: [
    {title: 'Table styles', filter: /^(td|tr)\./} // td.class and tr.class
  ]`

Comment: It does not work. I have tried to add it and it does not appear at all. Or where should I check her for just adding it? @Morpheus